# Regex input mask for angular?

Tags: regex, angularjs

The `ui-mask` in `Angular UI Utils' project ([link](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)) is a bit too limited.

For example, the first digit of a US phone number should be 2-9. In `ngPattern`, it should be

```
ng-pattern="/^\([2-9]\d{2}\)\d{3}-\d{4}(x\d{1,4})?$/"
```

So how can I write an input mask to prevent users from entering 0 or 1 in the first digit? Is there some better input mask we should use for Angular?

Comment: Not sure what you want. If you want to avoid entering those numbers at the beginning you can start your regex with `^[^01]`

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can find your answer here:
   https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/issues/16

As it is explained in the link  you can get the mask from a scope/controller variable, check the input and change the mask as needed like:

```
<input type="text" ui-mask="{{mask}}" ng-keyup="onKeyUp()" ng-model="myinput">


$scope.myinput = '';
var defaultMask  = '(99) 9999-9999';
$scope.mask = defaultMask;
$scope.onKeyUp = function(){
  if ($scope.myinput.slice(0,3) == '119') { // (11) 9 means mobile, or instead, you could use a regex
    $scope.mask = '(99) 99999-9999';
  } else {
    $scope.mask = defaultMask;
  }
};
```

Comment: Sure, There are so many useful comments in that link. But the best one in my point of view was this one.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing certain inputs based on a regex pattern for AngularJS

http://alphagit.github.io/ng-pattern-restrict/

Comment: This project is old and not maintained anymore. Could you provide an alternative?

Comment: sorry, but I didn't work with Angular for several years, not sure what to use now